# Monotouch 5 XIB.CS Gone?

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, xib

In Monotouch 5, I no longer see the option of iPhone View with Controller option in Monodevelop (I am using v2.8). What I see is the iPhone View and iPhone View Controller. And when selecting iPhone View Controller, it does not generate the xib.cs and xib.designer.cs files. So if you are modifying XIB file in XCode 4, the resulting changes are not getting reflrected in the designer.cs.

I have a feeling that I may be doing something wrong but can't put my finger to it. Can any one help me with how to generate xib.cs and xib.designer.cs files with latest releases of Monotouch and MonoDevelop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the changes in Xcode 4 the process had to be adjusted. You can now create a XIB from Monodevelop's file menu and you can add views or controllers.
They are no longer tied together.
See this doc about transitioning from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4:
http://docs.xamarin.com/@api/deki/files/261/=Transitioning_from_Xcode_3_to_Xcode_4_in_Monotouch.pdf

Also read into this: [Monodevelop 2.8, XCode 3.2.6, Interface Builder: Outlets and Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698167/monodevelop-2-8-xcode-3-2-6-interface-builder-outlets-and-actions)

Your question is kind of a duplicate.